# WPF Highly-Concurrent Cross-Thread UI Access

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

In C# I have several workers that do work and I need to reflect this into the UI. Update a progress bar, add items to a list and so on.

First time I tried to do this, I prepared everything with locks to make sure only one thread accesses the UI at every given moment but I got an exception. So I learned I need to use the `Dispatcher.Invoke` to access and change UI elements. It's quite cumbersome to enclose each UI change into an invoke but I can deal with it.

### My questions:

- **Is it necessary to synchronize the `Dispatcher.Invoke` calls or is that done internally?** So I wonder if I need to add another layer of protection with locks...
- **Does it impact performance having many update requests queued into the dispatcher?** So if several threads work and each of them reflects into the UI with a small change, how does issuing many calls to Dispatcher.Invoke` affect performance? Should I use a timer and only update UI once a second and queue all the UI changes internally?
- **Is there an easier way to do cross-thread access more inline... without Invokes?**

Comment: If you post some code (or pseudo-code) maybe we can help you. If you need to update the UI from within a thread (other than the UI thread) then you can't get away without dispatching to the main thread. Also, as you will notice in practice, you will need to throttle or aggregate UI updates from a point on.

Comment: @MarcelN. No need for code. Imagine a `Paraller.ForEach` for example that needs to update a `ProgressBar` and a `ListView` for each unit processed. Units range in tens of thousands, so quite a bit of activity to reflect in the UI without affecting performance as much as possible.

Comment: Progress bar... Maybe it will be fine with a lot of updates. ListView, not so much. I edited my previous comment, where I said that it may be necessary to aggregate UI updates. So instead dispatching for every new item, do it for every 5 new items. Otherwise you will notice a lag (depends also on the machine where you run it, so better to be cautious)

Comment: @MarcelN. I imagined... I'm used to C++ with basic Windows Controls so I sync my own cross-thread access. In C# it's strange. :)

Comment: Perhaps not really related to your main question, but instead of directly manipulating your UI through *Dispatcher.Invoke*, how about having a class with properties which reflect the respective state information (such as status label text or state of progress in % or whatever) through properties backed by an INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and use bindings in your UI to bind against those properties (yes, a kind of view model). -- This will take care of question #1 and #3 without you needing to deal with the Dispatcher in your code...

Comment: @elgonzo Good idea! Thanks. Just learning how data binding works. Will use this method when I have it better figured out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The human brain won't be able to process 200 updates/sec. It will just slow down your UI and not gain you anything.

Instead, make a timer that polls for status every, say, 200ms. This will be fast enough (5 updates/sec) not to be noticeable.

No need to lock on the dispatcher, it's handled internally. But you should dedicate your tasks to the computations, and not manipulate the UI from them. Implement a timer like I said, and use some standard way of cross-thread communication to retrieve the current status from the UI thread.

Comment: Yes, this is the proper solution. Set a timer that runs on the UI thread and checks the state of the worker processes every 200ms or so.

Comment: Yep, right answer. These `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` techniques are overused and severely abused.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it necessary to synchronize the Dispatcher.Invoke calls or is that done internally? So I wonder if I need to add another layer of protection with locks...

No, it is redundant.

> Does it impact performance having many update requests queued into the dispatcher? So if several threads work and each of them reflects into the UI with a small change, how does issuing many calls to Dispatcher.Invoke` affect performance? Should I use a timer and only update UI once a second and queue all the UI changes internally?

If you use `Invoke` and not `BeginInvoke`, you won't fill the queue (unless you have too many threads), each thread will just wait for its action to be processed by the dispatcher.

Spamming dispatcher may affect performance. You don't need to update UI too often. If you constantly wait for dispatcher, you'll just waste time and lose the benefits of multithreading.

A better option is to call `BeginInvoke` and do it not too often to avoid overwhelming main thread. This way, you won't waste time of the processing thread while waiting for UI to update.

> Is there an easier way to do cross-thread access more inline... without Invokes?

1. If you can put worker code inline, then async/await:

   ```
   UpdateUI();
   await Task.Run(...);
   UpdateUI();
   ```
2. If you use `Paraller.ForEach`, you can put progress value into a varaiable, atomically increment it, and update UI using timer.

Comment: Async/await won't work good for progress bars, or generally when you want to update the UI with stuff from a worker thread while the  thread is running.

Comment: I figured `async await` but it doesn't really apply in this scenario. But this is useful: `Spamming dispatcher may affect performance. You don't need to update UI too often. If you constantly wait for dispatcher, you'll just waste time and lose the benefits of multi-threading.`.